# safe way to pass parameter to database in mvc .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to .Net, I am told the following way increases the chance of SQL injection, can you show an example what I should do instead of writing my code like this?

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = null;
NpgsqlConnection con = null;

DataTable dt_datat_for_chart = new DataTable();

string cnction = null;
string cn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
con = new NpgsqlConnection(cn);

NpgsqlDataAdapter dataForGrid_Adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(@"select turbine_name,round(current_days_avg_winds_speed,2)
                                                                 Wind,round(current_days_availability,2) Avalability,current_days_production,last_state_change_timestamp::timestamp(0)
                                                                 from wpv.v_master_data_turbine v1
                                                                 JOIN zd.t_users g on(g.user_id=v1.pv_person_resp_id)

                                                                 AND current_turbine_status='" + statType + @"' order by last_state_change_timestamp desc", cn);
dataForGrid_Adapter.Fill(dt_datat_for_chart);
```

Comment: Make it a SQL Procedure in your database and set permissions on what logins can execute the stored procedure, then just pass the relevant parameters to the stored proc

Comment: You can use `NpgsqlParameter`

Comment: See this it should answer your question exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413359/how-to-use-sql-parameters-with-npgsqldataadapter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @FCin im using npgsql and for importing model first database to project i get 1000 different errors if i import views,so either i should add tables manually or like this stupid way,directly write sql in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this helps

```
 // 1. declare command object with parameter 
 NpgsqlCommand  cmd = new NpgsqlCommand ("select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);

 // 2. define parameters used in command object 
NpgsqlParameter  param = new NpgsqlParameter (); 
param.ParameterName = "@City"; 
param.Value         = inputCity;

 // 3. add new parameter to command object 
 cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: so with this way its safe or still sql injection is possible?

Comment: yes, it will. and for more detail refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/706692/Preventing-SQL-Injection-Attacks)

Comment: you are using the variable directly. without creating the parameter which shall act as loophole for the code.

Comment: my problem is in my controller i have many actionresult or methods,for each of them i need to write npgsqlconnection and this becoming a nightmare,do you know how can i get rid of this?

Comment: for that you should use an intermediate layer for database exchange, also you can find several [Helper classes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-web-api-using-sql-helper-class/) which is a good practice and also resolve nightmares.